# How to keep the state of switch on in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Just think of an Alarm Clock in Android, we turn the alarm clock for a specific time and the state of that time in switch is turned on but when I press back button or restart my app the switch comes to it default position that is Off. Kindly, please just tell me how to hold that position of Switch like they have in Alarm Clock.

Comment: Save switch state in share preference.and on create of application get switch state from share preference and set it to switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using SharedPreference you can save simple information about what you need, in the form "key = value". Here what you can do:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

//if your switch is off, you can write on your Shared Preference
editor.putString("switch_state","off");
//if on, instead
editor.putString("switch_state","on");

//to save your preference
editor.commit();
```

When you want to retrieve information about the state of your switch, you just have to read your Shared Preference file in this way:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

//here "off" is a default value.
String state = editor.getString("switch_state","off");

if(state.equals("off"))
    //Switch is off
if(state.equals("on"))
    //Switch is on
```

Comment: Is there anything I need to declare in Variables? Cuz I am getting an error Error:(39, 5) error: illegal start of statement.

Comment: Well, my code is not complete, of coursel. For example, the "if" statements don't have parentesis. Where I wrote "Switch is off" and "Switch is on" you can do stuff (that you need to do)